# Are textual criticism questions not allowed? Why?

Tags: discussion

I asked a que on [Genesis 2:2](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/94213/did-god-finish-working-on-the-sixth-day-or-the-seventh-genesis-22-confusion-ba) textual discrepancy Masoretic Text vs LXX and all others. Completed creation on seventh day, vs sixth day.  It was closed as off topic. Why is *textual criticism* tag allowed here if its questions are not? This kind of rules will create a barrier among the ChristianitySE readers from learning about textual criticism. Not many people would be the readers of Biblical Hermeneutics SE for that matter.

Comment: Textual Criticism questions generally belong on Biblical Hermeneutics. If there was a question that was specifically targeted towards a denomination then it could be asked here, but they should not be common. And a denomination shouldn't just be tacked on in order to keep it on this site. Because the subject generally just doesn't belong here.

Comment: then why does the tag of tc belong here?

Comment: For the few questions that do belong here.

Answer (score 1):

To curiousdannii's point in his comment that it is not a good idea to tack on a denomination. I'd say a denomination shouldn't be tacked on, unless you want an answer based on doctrine and not textual criticism, so it's one or the other.  I almost never post on BH because I only really care what a particular church says about scripture, it might be appropriate to ask a question about textual criticism under the light of some doctrine so that might be a justification for having that tag on the site, but as a standalone tag, no it's a question about Christian doctrine therefore it's too vague to be asked here.